# Can't Get jQuery Animated Scroll Working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I've been struggling to get an Animated scroll working on this site  [www.nicbrwn.com/dev](http://www.nicbrwn.com/dev)  but the scrolling only seems to work on Firefox and I need it to work on all platforms.
The jQuery I'm using to 'scroll' is here:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();    
            var target = this.hash,
                    $target = $(target);    
            $('body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
            }, 900, 'swing', function() {
                window.location.hash = target;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `overflow: auto` on the `body, html` in your css. That's what's stopping it.

Comment: This fix needs to be put on every single post about scrollTop not working in Chrome, I've been searching everywhere, and everyone was saying the exact same thing until I came across THIS answer, @jmore009 thank you

Answer (score 1):

Select both `html` and `body` elements:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({});
```